# Get the following character which match a string

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I'm trying to retreive a specific data returned from a command line. Here is my command line:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c community localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.2 | grep tun0
```

Which give me as result:

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr.4 = STRING: tun0
```

In this result I want to retreive `4`. I thought using regex, but maybe there is an easier way to fetch it.

Regex I tried :

`\ifDescr.\s+\K\S+` https://regex101.com/r/9X04MD/1

`[\n\r].*ifDescr.\s*([^\n\r]*)` https://regex101.com/r/9X04MD/2

I would like to fetch it in a single command line like

`snmpwalk -v2c -c community localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.2 | grep tun0 | ?`

Comment: There are no whitespace chars after the dot in the example data. Try `ifDescr.\s*\K\S+` or without the `\s*`

Comment: The regex works fine but when I want to make a single command line it returns nothing `snmpwalk -v2c -c community  localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.2 | grep tun0 | grep -o  'ifDescr.\s*\K\S+'`

Comment: Try `grep -oP` if you have for example gnu grep when using `\K` like `snmpwalk -v2c -c community localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.2 | grep tun0 | grep -oP 'ifDescr.\s*\K\S+'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend pattern `(?<=ifDescr\.)[^ =]+`

Explanation:

`(?<=ifDescr\.)` - positive lookbehind, asserts that wat is preceeding is `ifDescr.`

`[^ =]+` match one or more characters other than space or equal sign `=`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9X04MD/3)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many options that don't involve using GNU grep's experimental `-P` option. For example **given just your sample input to work off**, here's one way with any sed:

```
$ echo "$out" | sed 's/.*\.\([0-9]\).*tun0/\1/'
4
```

or any awk:

```
$ echo "$out" | awk -F'[. ]' '/tun0/{print $2}'
4
```